# Trying to use Utils from "@0x/protocol-utils" but it gives undefined

Tags: ethers.js, 0x, wagmi

I'm trying to use utils for signing a transaction for sellOrder of ERC721<->ERC20 as instructed here -
https://protocol.0x.org/en/latest/basics/orders.html#how-to-sign

```
import utils from '@0x/protocol-utils'
console.log(utils)

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(/* constructor params */)

const signature = await sellOrder.getSignatureWithProviderAsync(
    provider,
    utils.SignatureType.EIP712
  )
```

but utils from "@0x/protocol-utils" gives "undefined". Any help please?